# como realizar una Tienda Online?

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-4

Buenos dias chichos bueno miren mi pregunta es la siguiente donde puedo conseguir una pagina para realizar una **tienda online** lo mas rapido posible en laravel o php puro nose pero la necesito si alguno me pudiera facilitar se lo agradeseria mucho o si me pudieran explicar como hacerla tambien gracias espero su colaboracion....

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Jhon jairo, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado y realizar un poco de investigación!, saludos!

Comment: John, este tipo de preguntas regularmente son cerradas, trata de obtener reputación realizando buenas respuestas y preguntas y podrás acceder al [chat] donde hay varios expertos en este tema y te pueden brindar opiniones. Por lo pronto una búsqueda me  encontré : https://ceslava.com/blog/crea-tu-propia-tienda-online-con-php-y-ajax-2/  Saludos!

Comment: Tienda Online en Laravel o php "puro" no es compatible con rápido, si quieres que sea rápido usa Wordpress, Opencart... pero si quieres programarla desde 0, no va a ser rápido.

Comment: o sabes si me puedes facilitar un template para guiarme pero necesito hacerla yo mismo...

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa este:
https://www.prestashop.com/es

esta muy fácil de implementar y muy documentado. Tiene una comunidad muy activa y que te ayudan mucho. Ademas hay varios tutos sobre esto.

Espero te sirva, si ocupas ayuda aquí andamos :D

Comment: gracias pry me parese excelente vale estamos hablando bro gracias